# eclipse configuration files - link a source directory using variable

Tags: eclipse

When you add a folder in eclipse using `link a source directory` we can use variables. I need to know where these variables and their values are stored. Is it in a configuration file?

I followed the below , Went to eclipse, (java) project properties, and then java build path.

Now I clicked on link source and added a variable - say `top_root` and pointed to a location say - `c:\temp`

I used the same to link a source directory. This information is available in `.project` file.

I need to know, in which file `test=c:\temp` will be configured / available.

```
<link>
   <name>java</name>
   <type>2</type>
   <locationURI>top_root/src/java</locationURI>
</link>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: When you add a folder using "link a source directory" we can use variables. I need to know where these variables and their values are stored. Is it in a configuration file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eclipse-3.5.2\workspace\\.metadata\\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\\.settings\org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs`

The configuration was available, Inside the above folder, this file **`org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs`**

`pathvariable.top_root=C\:/temp`

search for all ***prefs*** files